# Error: The allow-in-static-site configuration tag is invalid when deploying my community to an organization

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I receive the following error message when try to deploy my ExperienceBundle:

**Error: For the MyCommunity/routes/serviceNotAvailable.json route, the allow-in-static-site configuration tag is invalid. Update your file, and try again.**

[serviceNotAvailable.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZez0.png)

```
{
  "activeViewId" : "ccb97685-3412-5431-8cee-cd7168363618",
  "appPageId" : "1b9a6145-fd12-42af-dc43-b7e91f71e3c2",
  "configurationTags" : [ "allow-in-static-site" ],
  "id" : "681ce2a0-63d9-417e-ba44-2z0c05375d35",
  "label" : "Service Not Available",
  "routeType" : "service-not-available",
  "type" : "route",
  "urlPrefix" : "service-not-available",
  "devName" : "Service_Not_Available__c"
}
```

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm?q=Assign+Salesforce+Site+Error+Pages#:%7E:text=Required.%20Represents%20the%20configuration%20tags%20for%20the%20route.%20The%20only%20supported%20value%20is%20allow%2Din%2Dstatic%2Dsite.%20Available%20in%20API%20Version%2051.0%20and%20later.) I can use this tag.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve it?

When I remove allow-in-static-site in **serviceNotAvailable.json** I receive the next error:

**The ServiceNotAvailable theme layout type cannot be used in MyCommunity/views/tooManyRequests.json. Update the file and try again.**

When I remove "configurationTags" property I receive error that this property is required.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Thx Ada, Done.)